# Why do these elements have spacing?

Tags: css

Why do the div with the classname *first* have 2px more than the image.(Inspect from Google Chrome), even though I set the `line-height` to 1, which mean the line gap is 0.(div tag with second classname have the correct height.)

## Code

```css
.first {
  background-color: blue;
  line-height: 1;
}

.first>img {}

.second {
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 1;
}

.second>span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190710/ourmid/pngtree-user-vector-avatar-png-image_1541962.jpg" alt="any picture">
</div>
<hr>

<div class="second">
  x<span>x</span>
</div>
```

Comment: There are many reasons. IT has its own default display type, margin, padding ,  height and varies in different operating systems, browsers and devices. Best thing is to create a reset.css and ensure both the image and div are display: block or inline-block.

Comment: `img{display:block}` also a solution.